# Add active class to 'home' link

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to add `active` class to the items on the main nav. However I am not able to get the `href` from the homepage in order to apply the `active` class to it.

This is what I've already tried:

```
<ul id="mainNavbar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $("#mainNavbar li a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
      $(this).addClass("active");
  })
});
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Have you tried debugging `pgurl` to see what it contains?

Comment: It's working for me, did you imported jquery?

Comment: Its working for me in a contrived example: https://jsfiddle.net/x9kLbgj4/1/ Can you provide an example input and expected vs actual output

Answer (score 0):

I created a teste.html file, and this works fine for me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

            $("#mainNavbar li a").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
                  $(this).addClass("active");
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="mainNavbar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
        <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="teste.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

replace this line

```
 $(this).attr('class','active'); // add this line
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $("#mainNavbar li a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
       $(this).attr('class','active'); // add this line
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use to put `active` class on html tag in your html page

like this:

```
<ul id="mainNavbar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
    <li>
        <a href="/" class="active">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="teste.html">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and on your contact page `add active class on <a> link` like this `<a href="contact.html" class="active">` and so on.